# Calling destructors on new placement buffer?

Tags: c++

So i have this class

```
class Obj{           //simple class with constructor + destructor

  public:
  Obj(){cout<<"Obj1 has been created"<<endl;}
  ~Obj(){cout<<"Obj1 has been destroyed"<<endl;}
  };


  Obj * buffer[10];  //buffer



  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  Obj * c = new(&buffer[0]) Obj;
  delete &buffer[0];
  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

Is this method of using placement "new" a valid one? because when i tried deleting the address, the destructor wasn't called.

but if i use this line of code, the destructor gets called

```
  Obj * c = new(&buffer[0]) Obj;
  delete c;
```

Can someone tell me what's happening? do i really have to delete the pointer to call out the destructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of placement new in your example as well as the attempt to destroy it are both invalid:

- The array `buffer` contains pointers to `Obj`. There is no guarantee that a pointer yields sufficient space for an object or that a pointer is properly aligned to hold an object of an object.
- To destroy an object constructed with placement new you'll need an explicit destructor call which looks something like `ptr->~Obj()`.

A proper use of placement could be something like this:

```
Obj*  objects[10];
char* buffers[10];
// ...
buffers[1] = new char[sizeof(Obj)];
objects[1] = new(buffers[1]) Obj();
// ...
objects[1]->~Obj();
delete[] buffers[1];
```

(obviously, in real code you'd protect the different buffers and objects by suitable RAII classes to avoid resource leaks).

Comment: So you used the char* buffer to store the address of objects?

Comment: Yes. This is where the buffer for the objects is being tracked. You could use one buffer for all objects, too.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be objects[1] = new(&buffers[1]) Obj(); ?

Answer (score 1):

With placement new you must call the destructor directly.

```
buffer[0].~Obj();

// or

c->~Obj();
```

You must **NOT** call delete on the object as this will try and release the memory. Since the memory was not allocated with new this is undefined behavior.

```
// delete &buffer[0];  Don't do this.
```